# unable to toggle Glyphicon

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to generate simple toggle function which can be used as thumbs up and thumbs down whenever an user will click on it. 
Problem is i am able to see the thumbs up icon but when i click it, thumbs down button doesn't show up. Please guide.
What I want is : To be able to toggle between thumbs up and thumbs down.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {

  isFavorite : boolean;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(){
    this.isFavorite=!this.isFavorite;
  }
}
```

My .ts file

```
<span 
class="glyphicon"
[class.glpyhicon-thumbs-down]="isFavorite"
[class.glyphicon-thumbs-up]="!isFavorite"
(click)="onClick()"
></span>
```

My .html file

I've installed bootstrap and mentioned the favorite element in app.component.html as well
I'm a newbie in this web development any suggestion would help
Thanks in advance!

Comment: does thumbs up icon disappears on clicking it or not?

Comment: Yes, it disappears. When I reload the page it appears again. What i want is when i click when the case is "thumbs up" it should show me "thumbs down" state. and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `[class.glpyhicon-thumbs-down]` structure, can you please try below one

```
<span
  class="glyphicon"
  [ngClass]="{'glpyhicon-thumbs-down': isFavorite,
  'glyphicon-thumbs-up': !isFavorite}"
  (click) = "onClick()"
  ></span >
```

Comment: `Can't bind to 'ng-class' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. ` this is the error I'm getting in the console

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? I am not facing any of such issue with about code snippet.

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

```
  <span 
class="glyphicon"
[class.glyphicon-thumbs-up]="isFavorite"
[class.glyphicon-thumbs-down]="!isFavorite"
(click)="onClick()"
></span>
```

I got it guys, I was calling the wrong class to a wrong boolean value. Above one I changed the position of the buttons :) thank you for your concerns